# Appledoc crashes on every use

Tags: ios, objective-c, appledoc

I hope this isn't a duplicate but after browsing the other issues I think its ok bring up the several issues I have been having with the Appledoc 2.2-963. I installed using brew which worked great, and apple doc has been generating me awesome documentation and what not, however it feels wrong to me that the software seg faults and breaks everytime i run it. Below is the script I use to run appledoc inside my working directory with the project files.

```
#! /bin/bash
appledoc \
--project-name "GSFDataCollector" \
--project-company "GSF SDP Team" \
--company-id "com.sdpllnl" \
--docset-feed-url "https://github.com/mbaptist23/open-fusion-ios" \
--docset-package-url "https://github.com/mbaptist23/open-fusion-ios" \
--docset-fallback-url "https://github.com/mbaptist23/open-fusion-ios" \
--output "~/help" \
--publish-docset \
--logformat xcode \
--keep-undocumented-objects \
--keep-undocumented-members \
--no-repeat-first-par \
--ignore "*.m" \
--ignore "*.mm" \
--ignore "GoogleMaps.bundle" \
--ignore "GoogleMaps.framework" \
--ignore "GSFDataCollecter.*" \
--ignore "Pods" \
--ignore "Podfile" \
--ignore "Podfile.lock" \
--ignore "LICENCE" \
--index-desc "./README.md" \
"."
```

In addition I am using the VVDocumenter found here: https://github.com/onevcat/VVDocumenter-Xcode.

Everything seems to generate fine, however here are some errors i get.
Segmentation fault: 11 and also the other error is something went wrong. (couldnt reproduce it for this quick issue). Anyway you get the point. It is crashing with every use.

Also here is an example of my documenting using VV

```
//
//  GSFSpinner.h
//  GSFDataCollecter
//
//  Created by Michael Baptist on 3/13/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Michael Baptist - LLNL. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GSFSpinner : UIView

/**
 *  Creates a default spinner in the middle of the screen. 
 *
 *  @return A new GSFSpinner.
 */
- (id)init;

/**
 *  Creates a spinner with custom size and custom location.
 *
 *  @param frame The frame for the new GSFSpinner to be used.
 *
 *  @return A new GSFSpinner with custom frame.
 */
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;

/**
 *  The actual spinner itself that is inside the custom view. Since this is a regular UIActivity spinner. The developer can customize it how ever they want.
 */
@property (nonatomic) UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;

/**
 *  Label that says why the spinner is spinning.
 */
@property (nonatomic) UILabel *label;

/**
 *  Width of the view containing the spinner.
 */
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger width;

/**
 *  Height of the view containing the spinner.
 */
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger height;

// sets the label text to white system font of size 14
/**
 *  Sets the label tetx to white system font of size 14.
 *
 *  @param text The text to be inserted into the label.
 */
- (void)setLabelText:(NSString*)text;

@end
```

I guess my question is, am I doing this correctly even though it is half working?
Also is there a way to generate the documentation as html in my working directory so I can push it to github as well (or is that not good practice)? I am just trying to learn this and there seems to be very little good usage examples out there except for the provided --help option and a few blogs that are pretty subpar IMO.

Anyway, thanks a lot hopefully others find this post helpful, because I do know others who have seen similar issues but just gave up, and I think this is a user error.

-- Michael Baptist

edit:

Also i forgot to mention that is also says that all of my classes are undocumented such as the example provided above. It this because I didn't finish or something or I'm doing it incorrectly.

ahh.. one last thing is there a way to link foundation classes into the docs as well. such as using a NSArray in a function and have that NSArray linkable to the main docsets.

Thanks again.

EDIT: 4/7/2014

here is a typical crash report.

```
2014-04-07 11:38:50.555 appledoc[69348:507] -[__NSCFArray errorHandleDataReceived:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fce10289f90
Oops, something went wrong...
NSInvalidArgumentException: -[__NSCFArray errorHandleDataReceived:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fce10289f90
@ 0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8399725c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
@ 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff857cae75 objc_exception_throw + 43
@ 2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8399a12d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
@ 3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff838f53f2 ___forwarding___ + 1010
@ 4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff838f4f78 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
@ 5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff83965e0c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
@ 6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff83859a6d _CFXNotificationPost + 2893
@ 7   Foundation                          0x00007fff863947ba -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68
@ 8   Foundation                          0x00007fff8648d450 _performFileHandleSource + 1548
@ 9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff838c8731 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
@ 10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff838b9f69 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 441
@ 11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff838b962f __CFRunLoopRun + 831
@ 12  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff838b90b5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
@ 13  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff892cba0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
@ 14  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff89417a81 GetNextEventMatchingMask + 349
@ 15  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8941787a WNEInternal + 168
@ 16  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff894177c6 WaitNextEvent + 52
@ 17  AppleScript                         0x000000010beefaf9 _Z19AEDefaultActiveProcPv + 131
@ 18  AppleScript                         0x000000010bef4400 _Z23InternalComponentActivej + 82
@ 19  AppleScript                         0x000000010bf229eb _Z13UASRemoteSendhhhhhPh + 653
@ 20  AppleScript                         0x000000010bf2dfdb _Z13UASValue_Sendhh14TUASClassIndexh + 329
@ 21  AppleScript                         0x000000010bf0950b _Z11UASExecute1v + 321
@ 22  AppleScript                         0x000000010bf09378 _Z10UASExecuteh + 188
@ 23  AppleScript                         0x000000010bed95ba _Z9ASExecutejjiPj + 460
@ 24  AppleScript                         0x000000010bed530d AppleScriptComponent + 845
@ 25  AppleScript                         0x000000010beef523 _ZN12AGenericCall8DelegateEP23ComponentInstanceRecord + 37
@ 26  AppleScript                         0x000000010beef4e9 _ZN15AGenericManager13HandleOSACallEP19ComponentParameters + 57
@ 27  AppleScript                         0x000000010beeeaf8 GenericComponent + 104
@ 28  OpenScripting                       0x00007fff8fc7bff1 OSAExecute + 72
@ 29  Foundation                          0x00007fff86455ae2 -[NSAppleScript(NSPrivate) _executeWithMode:andReturnError:] + 127
@ 30  appledoc                            0x00000001091223c4 appledoc + 304068
@ 31  appledoc                            0x0000000109109648 appledoc + 202312
@ 32  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff838cb479 __53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 137
@ 33  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff838cac1f -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 319
@ 34  appledoc                            0x0000000109109465 appledoc + 201829
@ 35  appledoc                            0x00000001090dbf9a appledoc + 16282
@ 36  appledoc                            0x00000001090da756 appledoc + 10070
@ 37  appledoc                            0x00000001090da956 appledoc + 10582
@ 38  appledoc                            0x00000001090d9e74 appledoc + 7796
@ 39  ???                                 0x000000000000002c 0x0 + 44
```

Comment: Without a crash report we can only do wild guesses which means basically nothing. Provide a symbolicated crash report, and most likely then discuss that with the appledoc developer on GitHub.

Comment: has this ever been resolved?